# What is core framework version in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, http-headers, clr

What is core framework version in ASP.NET, is it **CLR** version?  I mean in am using ASP.NET 3.5, then HTTP header X-AspNet-Version shows version as **2.0.50727**.

Answer (score 0):

These versions may seem a bit confusing. But basically yes, they refer to the underlying .NET framework version of your ASP.NET dlls (it consists of `aspnet_isapi.dll`, `aspnet_compiler.exe` etc) which you can find under `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework directory`.

See more details here

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jamesche/2007/09/25/asp-net-version-madness/

and here

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2008/03/20/where-is-asp-net-3-5-on-iis/